# Group chapter bookmarks into separate added bookmark

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, scrbook

I'm designing a book with an elaborate ToC. I'd like to keep the ToC the way it is, but would like to make the bookmarks in the PDF a little less overwhelming, by grouping chapter together.

MWE:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks, bookmarksopen=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{Question PDF bookmarks}
\author{Alex Dijk}
\date{April 2022}

\begin{document}

\chapter{1 jan}First January lecture
\chapter{2 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{3 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{4 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{5 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{6 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{7 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{8 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{1 feb}First February lecture
\chapter{2 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{3 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{4 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{5 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{6 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{7 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{8 feb}Another February lecture

\end{document}
```

So here, I would like to add bookmarks called 'January' and 'February' to the resulting PDF (but not to the ToC). These additional bookmarks then need to be unopened by default, under which all of the individual January and February chapters are ordered. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a current hyperref you can do this (inputenc is no longer needed in a current latex, utf8 is the default since a few years anyway):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hidelinks, bookmarksopen=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{Question PDF bookmarks}
\author{Alex Dijk}
\date{April 2022}

\begin{document}

\bookmark[level=part,dest=\hyperget{anchor}{chap:jan}]{January}
\chapter{1 jan}\label{chap:jan}First January lecture
\chapter{2 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{3 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{4 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{5 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{6 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{7 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{8 jan}Another January lecture
\cleardoublepage
\bookmark[level=part,dest=\hyperget{anchor}{chap:feb}]{February}
\chapter{1 feb}\label{chap:feb}First February lecture
\chapter{2 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{3 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{4 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{5 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{6 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{7 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{8 feb}Another February lecture

\end{document}
```

[image]

On older systems you must create targets manually:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hidelinks, bookmarksopen=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{Question PDF bookmarks}
\author{Alex Dijk}
\date{April 2022}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{jan}{}
\bookmark[level=part,dest=jan]{January}
\chapter{1 jan}First January lecture
\chapter{2 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{3 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{4 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{5 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{6 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{7 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{8 jan}Another January lecture
\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{feb}{}
\bookmark[level=part,dest=feb]{February}
\chapter{1 feb}\label{chap:feb}First February lecture
\chapter{2 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{3 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{4 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{5 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{6 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{7 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{8 feb}Another February lecture

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this in my `scrbook` environment, but now the compiling times out, which it didn't do before... I have many `\addchap{}` entries, instead of `\chapter`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Parvana It should work in scrbook to. Ask a new question with a small, but complete example demonstrating the problem. Did you test my example? Does it work for you?

Comment: I'll do that. Yes, your answer did work, although I did get this 'Undefined control sequence'-error log:
`\BKM@dest ->\hyperget 
                      {anchor}{chap:jan}
l.11 ...dest=\hyperget{anchor}{chap:jan}]{January}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., '\hobx'), type 'I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., 'I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.`

Comment: If you get an error then it didn't work. As I wrote this requires a current hyperref,  yours is to old.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means that my hyperref is too old and how to resolve that as a user of Overleaf...

Comment: I added some code that should work also on overleaf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135554/discussion-between-parvana-and-ulrike-fischer).