# Hyperref & bookmarks: reset and/or change levels bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

My [initial question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640754/group-chapter-bookmarks-into-separate-added-bookmark/640757#640757) was answered, but now a new issue has arisen. It relates to the bookmarks in the PDF. I am working with Overleaf, which does not have the current `hyperref` but an older one. In the following MWE the backmatter chapters are ordered under the 'February' bookmark. But I don't want that. How do I prevent this? I would just like the bookmarks of the backmatter to be created the way the bookmarks for the frontmatter are.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hidelinks, bookmarksopen=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{preface}
\chapter{introduction}

\mainmatter

\hypertarget{jan}{}
\bookmark[level=part,dest=jan]{January}
\chapter{1 jan}First January lecture
\chapter{2 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{3 jan}Another January lecture

\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{feb}{}
\bookmark[level=part,dest=feb]{February}
\chapter{1 feb}First February lecture
\chapter{2 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{2 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{3 feb}Another February lecture


\cleardoublepage
\backmatter
\chapter{appendix A}
\chapter{appendix B}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the `bookmark` documentation. It is to start a new tree immediately after the `\backmatter` by adding `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hidelinks, bookmarksopen=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{introduction}

\hypertarget{jan}{}
\bookmark[level=part,dest=jan]{January}
\chapter{1 jan}First January lecture
\chapter{2 jan}Another January lecture
\chapter{3 jan}Another January lecture
\cleardoublepage
\hypertarget{feb}{}
\bookmark[level=part,dest=feb]{February}
\chapter{1 feb}First February lecture
\chapter{2 feb}Another February lecture
\chapter{3 feb}Another February lecture

\cleardoublepage
\backmatter
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\chapter{appendix A}
\chapter{appendix B}

\end{document}
```